# C++ Directx 11 Trying to XMMatrixTranslation a cube

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

Trying to modify the cube position with the XMMatrixTranslation function.  Attached is the code...

// Rotate and modify position of cube around the origin
    g_World = XMMatrixRotationY( t );

```
g_World = XMMatrixMultiply(g_World, XMMatrixTranslation(0, yDirection, 0));

// Modify the color
g_vMeshColor.x = ( sinf( t * 1.0f ) + 1.0f ) * 0.5f;
g_vMeshColor.y = ( cosf( t * 3.0f ) + 1.0f ) * 0.5f;
g_vMeshColor.z = ( sinf( t * 5.0f ) + 1.0f ) * 0.5f;

//
// Clear the back buffer
//
float ClearColor[4] = { 0.0f, 0.125f, 0.3f, 1.0f }; // red, green, blue, alpha
g_pImmediateContext->ClearRenderTargetView( g_pRenderTargetView, ClearColor );

//
// Clear the depth buffer to 1.0 (max depth)
//
g_pImmediateContext->ClearDepthStencilView( g_pDepthStencilView, D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH, 1.0f, 0 );

//
// Update variables that change once per frame
//
CBChangesEveryFrame cb;
cb.mWorld = XMMatrixTranspose( g_World );
cb.vMeshColor = g_vMeshColor;
g_pImmediateContext->UpdateSubresource( g_pCBChangesEveryFrame, 0, NULL, &cb, 0, 0 );

//
// Render the cube
//
g_pImmediateContext->VSSetShader( g_pVertexShader, NULL, 0 );
g_pImmediateContext->VSSetConstantBuffers( 0, 1, &g_pCBNeverChanges );
g_pImmediateContext->VSSetConstantBuffers( 1, 1, &g_pCBChangeOnResize );
g_pImmediateContext->VSSetConstantBuffers( 2, 1, &g_pCBChangesEveryFrame );
g_pImmediateContext->PSSetShader( g_pPixelShader, NULL, 0 );
g_pImmediateContext->PSSetConstantBuffers( 2, 1, &g_pCBChangesEveryFrame );
g_pImmediateContext->PSSetShaderResources( 0, 1, &g_pTextureRV );
g_pImmediateContext->PSSetSamplers( 0, 1, &g_pSamplerLinear );
g_pImmediateContext->DrawIndexed( 36, 0, 0 );

//
// Present our back buffer to our front buffer
//
g_pSwapChain->Present( 0, 0 );
```

When I press the down button the position of the cube is supposed to change in the negative y direction.  The cube disappears when the I press the key.

Thanks,

Scott

Comment: you can check the value of yDirection, if it is too big, the cube may went out of the view.

Comment: The value of yDirection is itself + 10.

Comment: then what's the size of your cube?

Comment: I am guessing that you may add 10 to yDirection every frame when you press button. So few seconds  later, yDirection will grow to hundreds. Try to record a delta time(dt) between frames, and use `yDirection += dt * velocity` instead.

Comment: 10 x 10 x 10 is the size of the cube.

Comment: It seems that was precisely what was happening.  I added a counter to the keypress, so that each keypressed was recorded and I recorded it to 14.  Thanks.